# Why Are Fixed-Sized Array-Backed Collections Allowed to not Implement all Interface Methods?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Set<String> strings = map1.keySet();
strings.addAll(map2.ketSet());
```

At run-time, I'm getting an UnsupportedOperationException, and it seems that this is happening because `strings` is a fixed-sized array-backed set.  But if `strings` is a `set`, why it it allowed to not implement `addAll`?

Comment: read the doc --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection- _UnsupportedOperationException - if the `addAll` operation is not supported by this collection_

Comment: It _has_ implemented the interface. The implementation happens to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` exception, though, since that method is not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is clearly mentioned in the javadoc of [`keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) (emphasis mine)

> [...]  The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. **It does not support the add or addAll operations.**

Also, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218056/why-are-fixed-sized-array-backed-collections-allowed-to-not-implement-all-interf/50218104#comment87453146_50218056) not all collections have to implement this method.

More specifically - it ([addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) of Collection) says,

> UnsupportedOperationException - if the addAll operation is not supported by this collection

Comment: ...and perhaps more to the point, from the JavaDoc for [`Collection#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-): *"Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection **(optional operation)**."* *(my emphasis)*

Answer (score 1):

First the solution:

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>(map1.keySet());
strings.addAll(map2.ketSet());
```

The problem that not the full interface API is supported by such backing class is simply due to the fragmentary nature of a very tight fitting implementation. For instance writing back to the original collection.

So it is a matter of either **efficiency** or **backing** (write-back) of the original collection, or both.

The wish for a more full gamma of operations can be easily done, as above.

Answer (score 0):

The set created from the keySet method does not support add or addAll because the set is mapped to the original map, and you can't add a key to a map without also adding a value.